# how to make php image link open in a new window

Tags: php, html, database, image, hyperlink

I had make a php link but i want it to open in a specific size in a new window.Can anyone from here suggest anything?The link is an image.

```
echo "<td><center><a href=\"edituser.php?id=$row[id]\"><img src=image/edit.png></a></center></td>";
```

the link is connect with the database.It will open a form to edit user data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open in a new window, you have to add target to your a tag, eg:

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Example Link</a>
```

To configure the size it's opened at, afaik you'd have to use javascript,

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;">Example Link</a>
```

Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TGq5y/)

Comment: i think `target="_blank"` is about new tab

Comment: @BhavinRana I think that will depend on your browser settings, as you can choose to open links in new windows or tabs.

Comment: this wont work with 'echo' and it is not open in a new window

Comment: @noooooooooooooo The javascript-less version will only open a new window if your browser settings are configured to open links in a new window. The version using javascript will open a new window. Both will work with echo, if they're not then there's something wrong with your code when implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo "<td><center><a target='_blank' href=\"edituser.php?id=$row[id]\"><img src=image/edit.png></a></center></td>";
```

Comment: this one open as a new tab.not new window

Answer (score 0):

This should open it in a new window:

```
<a target="_blank" href=\"edituser.php?id=$row[id]\"><img  width="200" height="150" src=image/edit.png></a>
```

you can add "width" and "height" attributes to the "img" tag.

Comment: this one only make the image bigger

Answer (score 0):

I tried above code, but doesn't work. Instead of "_blank", I used "new"

```
echo '<a href="www.google.com" target="new" > <img src="small.jpg"></a></div>';
```

I'm not very sure about the quote. You may test out.